# Python 3.5, using a declared variable is slower compared to using its value directly?

Tags: python, variables

Option 1:

```
b = 1
for i in range(1000000):
    a = b in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Option 2:

```
b = 1
c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
for i in range(1000000):
    a = b in c
```

Option 1 is faster than Option 2, I would thought Option2 should be faster. Does this have anything to do with stack or heaps? or is this about how python optimize its loops? or is it a dictionary namespace related?

I am asking this because usually option2, the slower version, is a better coding practice. Option1 is way too hardcoded.

Comment: Generally, hardcoded values are faster than their variable counterparts. This holds true tor most programming languages. But best practice suggests to use variables or #define type declarations.

Comment: In option1, I have a feeling that python is not initializing {1,2,3,4,5} in the loop everytime, it probably assigned it to a fixed location in memory first time, and use that fixed location for the subsequent comparison. And I am guessing python did not do the same for option 2, because python expects that 'c' may change in value in the middle of the loop? I would try it out if I can declare a constant in python, I can not.

Comment: The variable lookup again points to a memory location, so it should not take up much time in such a small program, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no noticeable difference, most probably because of caching of the results and other compile time optimizations.

But is you take the results of the slowest runs as significant (maybe they are?), it seems that the second one's slowest run is 3 to 4 times slower than the first. (maybe it is the true speed of execution before anything gets cached and optimized? IDK)

### The first one:

```
%%timeit
def f1(b, c):
    for i in range(1000000):
        a = b in c
```

**result:**

```
The slowest run took 30.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 123 ns per loop
```

### The second one:

```
%%timeit
def f2(b):
    for i in range(1000000):
        a = b in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

**result:**

```
The slowest run took 8.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 126 ns per loop
```

ipython 3.4.4, anaconda, in Jupyter notebook, on an oldish macbook air

Comment: thanks, I think it is safe to assume that I shouldn't really worry about this issue.